# How do I find elements with selenium that don't have a name | python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, discord

I have a question.
I am trying to access a search field with Selenium, but this has no name and no ID in the html code.
Does anyone know how I can get the search field so that I can write something in it with selenium?

[Html Code of the search field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGsGn.png)

[Complete Html Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvy7E.png)

Comment: Try to [locate elements by XPath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath). Also try to search for similar questions already asked in stackoverflow before asking, it has been asked many many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the `xpath` for that like from you screenshot:

```
//input[@type='text']
```

You can learn more about `xpath` from [here](https://devhints.io/xpath)